How to make paragraphs distributed across two columns start at the same height in both columns
I'm trying to create a page that looks like this:

if my code looks like
\twocolumn
blindtext
\command{title}{blindtext}{blindtext}
\command{title}{blindtext}{blindtext}
\command{title}{blindtext}{blindtext}
\command{title}{blindtext}{blindtext}
\command{title}{blindtext}{blindtext}
\command{title}{blindtext}{blindtext}

and the code of \command is something like
\newcommand{\command}[3]{
    \begin{tcolorbox}[options]
        #1
    \end{tcolorbox}
    textit{#2}\\
    #3
}

how can I make sure the instances of \command start at the same heigh on both columns like in the figure?

The optional argument of \twocolumn is printed in \onecolumn format.  Just put the text into a minipage {\dimexpr 0.5\textwidth+0.5\columnsep}.  Better yet, use the whole `page width.
